# Writing to file system. How to lock effectively

Tags: c#, multithreading, filesystems, locking

I'm writing a `Stringbuilder` to file

```
   using (FileStream file = new FileStream(Filepath, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read))
   using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(file, Encoding.Unicode))
   {
        writer.Write(text.ToString());
   }
```

This is equivilent (I think)

```
   File.AppendAllText(Filepath, text.ToString());
```

Obviously in a multi threaded environment these statements on their own would cause failures to write as they collided.
I've put a `lock` on this code, but that isn't ideal, **as it's too expensive and may exacerbate this bottleneck**. Is there some other way of causing one threads file access to block another's. I've been told "blocking not locking", I thought `lock` did block, but they must be hinting at a cheaper way of preventing simultaneous use of the file system.

How do I block execution in a less time expensive manner?

Comment: "as it's too expensive and may exacerbate this bottleneck" - this is a misconception. Locks are very fast, writing to the file is slow. Writing to the same file from multiple threads is going to be even  slower in most cases, unless device provides multi-threaded write hardware capabilities  (I haven't seen any, but I think they may exist).

Comment: If that fragment is a bottleneck, it is because you are opening and closing a file handle every time you write. It would be much faster to keep the file open and flush the writer when needed.

Comment: To add to @oleksii comment: writing to the same *disk drive* from multiple threads is going to be slower in most cases.

Comment: I think bigger penalty you have is in constantly opening stream and closing (they way you have your code, each thread would be doing that), rather than locking.  Locking in your context doesn't seem to be bad, but I'd create stream once and share among threads, and then lock on it, to make it more efficient

Comment: Good points about keeping the file open. It had occurred to me to use a background process, but I thought it would be overkill. I'll keep it as is and if it is a bottleneck reassess that decision.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't have multiple threads write to the same file simultaneously, thus, there is no such "bottleneck" . A `lock` makes perfect sense for this scenario. If you are concerned about this being expensive, just add the writes to a queue, and let a single thread manage writing them to file.

Pseudo code

```
public static readonly Object logsLock = new Object();

// any thread
lock(logsLock) 
{
    logs.Add(stringBuilderText);
}

// dedicated thread to writing
lock(logsLock)
{
    // ideally, this should be a "get in, get out" situation, 
    // where you only need to make a copy of the logs, then exit the lock, 
    // then write them, then lock the logsLock again, and remove only the logs 
    // you successfully wrote to to file, then exit the lock again.
    logs.ForEach(writeLogToFile);
}
```

Comment: I believe you can have multiple threads write to the same stream (I can't think of anything that would actually prevent it), and they'll write interleaved (thus likely corrupting the output).  Yes you can have producer-consumer set up as you suggest, but the sample code you posted lacks signaling which is needed (logs are probably not added in one single batch and only once). So in such case you probably need not `lock` but use `ConcurrentQueue<T>` which has built-in signaling.

Answer (score 1):

You can lock the stream using the lock method.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.lock.aspx

Comment: Based on Remark of that link: _"Locking a range of a file stream gives the threads of the locking process exclusive access to that range of the file stream."_ I believe that would be for cross-process locking, not cross-thread within same process.

Comment: Here is another option use [File.Open](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y973b725(v=vs.110).aspx) with the option [FileShare.None](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileshare(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thanks. However, I'm not sure Fileshare.None is a valid option as I'm pretty sure if another thread hits that file it won't get blocked it will go bang.

Comment: Maybe, but according to another post the request to the file will be queued.
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23546564/writing-to-file-system-how-to-lock-effectively/23546701?noredirect=1#comment36126723_23546701)